# declare "ready to call" functions

Tags: node.js, module

In nodeJS is it possible to declare multiple functions in a module and exports them as "ready to call" ? Like `it` and `describe` functions in the `supertest` and `mocha` modules.
I looked in but I do not understand where the functions are defined.

If yes: is it possible to require the file in one place to make the functions accessible from anywhere?
Or maybe this is not a "good practice"

**utils.js**

```js
function foo(val) {
    console.log(val*2);
}

function bar(val) {
    console.log(typeof val);
}

module.exports = {
    foo,
    bar
}
```

**moduleOne.js** (expected):

```js
const utils = require('./utils');

// call without use 'utils.[...]'
foo(5);
bar('string');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, you just have to import using a method that's called "destructuring assignment".

```
const {foo, bar} = require('./utils');

foo(5);
bar('string');
```

However, you need to import them in every file you need them, they are cached so it won't read them from disk every time. You could also set them on global and you'd be able to achieve the same thing, but it's quite a bad practice in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, know you say me it's better to use destructuring for what I want. I will not do the "global" declaration